# Появление select в зависимости от выбора option

Tags: php, html, form, select

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать (желательно с помощью php) данную форму:

```html
<h2>Заказ билетов</h2>
<form action="core.php" method="post">
  <p><select name="row" id="row" required="required">
      <option value="">Ряд</option>
      <option value="1">Первый</option>
      <option value="2">Второй</option>
      <option value="3">Третий</option>
    </select></p>
  <p><select name="placeRow1" id="placeRow1" required="required">
      <option value="">Место</option>
      <option value="1">Первое</option>
      <option value="2" disabled="disabled">Второе</option>
      <option value="3">Третье</option>
    </select></p>
  <p><select name="placeRow2" required="required">
      <option value="">Место</option>
      <option value="1">Первое</option>
      <option value="2">Второе</option>
      <option value="3" disabled="disabled">Третье</option>
    </select></p>
  <p><select name="placeRow3" required="required">
      <option value="">Место</option>
      <option value="1" disabled="disabled">Первое</option>
      <option value="2">Второе</option>
      <option value="3">Третье</option>
    </select></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Нужно чтобы при выборе ряда выпадал `select`, который присвоен своему ряду по номеру.

Comment: Так в чём именно проюлема?

Comment: нужно чтоб при выборе первого ряда выпадал placeRow1, при выборе второго ряда появлялся placeRow2

Comment: Ну, это я понял, что не получается именно?

Comment: @RomanGrinyov найти выход на решение задачи, просто легкий способ